# Meta Images Being Dynamically Pulled from MySQL Issue

Tags: php, meta

I'm trying to pull an image (stored in a BLOB) from my MySQL database and set it to the meta image tag for OG and Twitter.

```
echo '<meta property="og:type" content="article" />';
echo '<meta property="og:title" content="'.$meta_title.'" />';
echo '<meta property="og:description" content="'.$meta_description.'" />';
echo '<meta property="og:image" content="'.imagepng(imageCreateFromString($meta_img)).'" />';
echo '<meta property="og:site_name" content="The Creator" />';

echo '<meta name="twitter:title" content="'.$meta_title.'" />';
echo '<meta name="twitter:description" content="'.$meta_description.'" />';
echo '<meta name="twitter:image" content="'.imagepng(imageCreateFromString($meta_img)).'" />';
echo '<meta name="twitter:creator" content="@Creator" />';
```

It's not an issue with my image (I've used it elsewhere by just Base64 encoding it). I'm a bit lost because Base64encode doesn't seem to work here. Help?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't seem to work?" What is showing up and what were you expecting to show up? Also, `<meta property="og:image">` expects the content to be a URL, not a Base64 image, so that's probably your problem.

Comment: Sorry, too vague on my part. I'm using the Twitter card validator, and the image won't show, but the title and description will. Is there any workaround to not using a URL? My articles are pulled from a database and it'd be convenient if I didn't have to generate a URL for each cover image. I display the image on the page where the keywords are. Would there possibly be a way to reference that? Thanks.

Comment: Since you're using PHP, you should be able to specify a URL that outputs the image specific to that article. I can post example code but first I'll need to know more details: what is the primary key of your articles table, and how is that passed to your PHP script?

Comment: Was able to figure that out myself. Just required a bit more thought. Thanks!